# FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/SerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am processing the twitter data to hive external table, but while creating hive external table I get an error. Please look into the my code in below.

1. Added the jar file to move the hive/lib location.
2. Added to the jar file hive by using following command
     I have add the flowing jars in hive lib directory:

   ```
   ADD JAR /usr/local/hive/lib/hive-serdes-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;
   ```

   Please find the external hive table:

   ```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Mytweets_raw (
   id BIGINT,
   created_at STRING,
   source STRING,
   favorited BOOLEAN,
   retweet_count INT,
   retweeted_status STRUCT<text:STRING,tuser:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
   entities STRUCT<urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
   user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
   hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
   text STRING,
   tuser STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING,friends_count:INT,followers_count:INT,statuses_count:INT,verified:BOOLEAN,utc_offset:INT,time_zone:STRING>,
   in_reply_to_screen_name STRING )
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
   LOCATION 'hdfs://localhost:54310/data/tweets_raw';
   ```

   After this I am getting following error message, please any body can help on this?

More information: My current environment is

- Hadoop 2.9.0
- Hive 2.3.2

Comment: Welcome to SO. I reformatted your question so that the code is displayed properly. When you want to use a code block in an enumeration you have to indent the code by an additional four spaces.

Comment: Your JAR file needs to be on all nodes of the cluster, or you must add from HDFS

Comment: this is single node cluster . but i have already added the hive library.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, 
I just needed to replace the serde format from 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'  to  'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe', and the error was resolved in my case. Good luck !!

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets4 (
    id BIGINT,
    created_at STRING,
    source STRING,
    favorited BOOLEAN,
    retweet_count INT,
    retweeted_status STRUCT<
    text:STRING,
    `user`:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
    entities STRUCT<
    urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
    user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
    hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
    text STRING,
    `user` STRUCT<
    screen_name:STRING,
    name:STRING,
    friends_count:INT,
    followers_count:INT,
    statuses_count:INT,
    verified:BOOLEAN,
    utc_offset:INT,
    time_zone:STRING>,
    in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
 )
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
 LOCATION '/twitter-project/project1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Error code 1 signifies permission issue. It will be really difficult to identify the issue (Mostly environment issue). There can be many reasons why we are getting this error. Try below cases and see if you are getting same error.

1) Check you have permissions to create tables(Hive path).

2)  Create    simple Hive external table(You can confirm you have access for meta    store)

3) Create Simple External Hive table by pointing to HDFS    location( You can confirm your access permissions for HDFS path)

4)    Create Simple External Hive table by pointing to local path ( You    can confirm your access permissions for local path)

5) Check you have 777 permissions for the jar location.

I suggest try multiple cases where there is possibility of permission issue apart from the above.

Comment: Almost never a good idea to do 777 perms, especially on a jar.